# Learndash how to get course title from course ID

Tags: php, learndash

I looked all over the Learndash documentation but I'm unable to find a function to obtain the course title from a course id. Does anyone know how to do this or have some sample code ?

Logged in users can see the certificates they've earned so that they can click the link and download any certificate. Below is the code I currently have. I get the list of currently enrolled courses into `$arr1` array. This is an array of `Course IDs`. I'm going through this array and for any course that is `completed`, I'm allowing user a link to download the course.

Currently, I can get the course download link using function `learndash_get_course_certificate_link`. However, I want to display the name of the course (course title) in the text of the a href.

The text `DOWNLOAD YOUR PROJECT MANAGEMENT CERTIFICATE`, `DOWNLOAD YOUR ACCOUNTING CERTIFICATE`, etc is what I want to display for each certificate.

```
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();          
        $arr1 = learndash_get_user_course_access_list($current_user->ID );                  
        
        foreach ($arr1 as $value) 
        {               
            $val = learndash_course_status($value);             
            if ($val == "Completed")
            {                       
                $certificate_link = learndash_get_course_certificate_link($value);
                echo '<a href="'.$certificate_link.'">DOWNLOAD YOUR PROJECT MANAGEMENT CERTIFICATE</a>';
                echo '<br>';                    
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

OK, I found the answer. All I have to do is call the php function: get_post(...). This gets me the title of the course:

```
$course = get_post($course_id);
echo $course->post_title;
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your solution it helped me to get the title of the course, but in my case, I don't have an id of the course (because I make the same course page (as style ) for all courses so I want to display the title dynamically) and in my case, I have generated a new shortcode for the title so I can use it wherever I want.
this is the code :

```
add_shortcode( 'lmscoder-course-title', 'lmscoder_course_title' );
function lmscoder_course_title() {
    // go away if LearnDash isn't active
    if ( ! function_exists( 'learndash_get_course_meta_setting' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    //get course id 
    $id = learndash_get_course_id();
    $course = get_post($id);
     // return the title
    return $course->post_title; 
   
}
```

hope it helps.